# OneTab data recovery from old boot drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, google-chrome-extensions

My computer failed, so I removed my SSD to connect it to my new computer (as an external hard drive).

Is there a way to recover all of my [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall?hl=en) data from the old drive? What is the path to this data?

Comment: (Referenced in [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374235/).)